Comparison of experimental and theoretical FAB+-MS spectra of a PdLClDMSO complex
So I have been characterizing some samples through FAB+-MS and found this:

I am pretty sure that the isotope distribution is correct, but I think there are some deviations which could be due to [M]+ and [M+1]+ ions, however I don't know how to account for that in the isotope distribution calculator. It is a PdLClDMSO complex where L is a thiosemicarbazone and formula C11H9N5ClSPdClC2H6SO. Do you think it is correct? I know there's some slight deviation at m/z 498 but I don't know if it could be due to the equipment or some other reason. Thanks for your help!


I'm not sure what you mean by deviations due to [M]+ and [M+1]+ ions.  Do you mean you have both $\ce{C11H9N5ClSPdClC2H6SO^{.+}}$ radical cations and $\ce{[C11H9N5ClSPdClC2H6SO + H]+}$ protonated cations?

In any case, here's how I predict isotopic distributions.  I use an R-based tool that enumerates all the possible isotopomers and the exact mass for each, then explicitly lump species of the same integer mass together to calculate distributions for mass spectrometers that can't resolve isotopic "fine structure".
require(tidyverse)
require(ecipex)

options(repr.plot.width=8, repr.plot.height=4)

 my_graph <- 
     ecipex('C11H9N5ClSPdClC2H6SO')[[1]] %>%
     mutate(integer_mass = round(mass, 0)) %>%
     group_by(integer_mass) %>%
     mutate(intensity = sum(abundance), 
            mass = sum(abundance*intensity) / sum(abundance)) %>%
     ggplot(aes(x = integer_mass, y = intensity, ymin = 0, ymax= intensity)) +
         geom_errorbar(width=0)

 my_graph

It gives a graph like this:

That matches your theoretically predicted distribution well.  But there are some minor discrepancies.

If you wanted to model a mixture of two different ion types, here's one way to do it.  (Note: I'm not taking care here about the mass of electrons, all my computed exact m/z values will be off, but I'm just plotting integer mass and I think this example is still illustrative.)
 radical_cation <- 
     ecipex('C11H9N5ClSPdClC2H6SO')[[1]] %>%
     mutate(integer_mass = round(mass, 0)) %>%
     group_by(integer_mass) %>%
     summarize(intensity = sum(abundance), 
               mass = sum(abundance*mass) / sum(abundance)) %>%
     select(integer_mass, intensity)


 protonated_cation <- 
     ecipex('C11H9N5ClSPdClC2H6SOH')[[1]] %>%  # notice extra "H"
     mutate(integer_mass = round(mass, 0)) %>%
     group_by(integer_mass) %>%
     summarize(intensity = sum(abundance), 
               mass = sum(abundance*mass) / sum(abundance)) %>%
     select(integer_mass, mass, intensity)


 # assume a 85% / 15% mixture of radical to protonated
 combined <- 
     full_join(radical_cation, protonated_cation, by='integer_mass') %>%
     replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
     mutate(combined_intensity = 0.85*intensity.x + 0.15*intensity.y) %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     mutate(normalized_intensity = combined_intensity / max(combined_intensity) * 100)

 my_graph %+% {combined}

This gives a graph like this:

I've assumed a 85/15 mixture, but you could adapt this to write a fitting routine to find a best fit mixture ratio if you wanted, or just play with the example until it matched your data better.

Mass spectrometers are very good at mass (or m/z) accuracy.  Depending on the type of detector you use (TOF vs. Orbitrap vs. triple quad vs. ICR etc.), they are usually less good at intensity accuracy.  Departures of up to 20% - 30% (relative % -- so a peak that should be 10% of max intensity could be 12 or 13% etc.) of a theoretically predicted intensity can be caused by various technical factors.  This commonly affects low-intensity peaks the most.


